# How to divide the controller?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, swing, controller

My View-Controller

```
public class MainForm implements java.util.Observer{
@Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        System.err.println("update View ....");
        this.textField_15.setText(String.valueOf(model.getThermalConductivity()));
            /*
*****
*/


    }
}
```

In the model I use methods

```
setChanged();
notifyObservers();
```

All events model updates are processed in the method "update"

How to divide the controller?

Comment: The MainForm looks like your view to me as it has text fields and other GUI thingies. Maybe I'm wrong, but I think of the GUI listeners as more of the control aspect.

Comment: First off, avoid using java.util.Observer, this is probably the worst implementation of the observer pattern.

Comment: @jfpoilpret: [`java.util.Observable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) has the advantage of being simple and understandable, but your point is otherwise well-taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might enjoy trying this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066590/gui-problem-after-rewriting-to-mvc/3072979#3072979). For simplicity, the model extends `Observable`, but several other approaches are mentioned with links to examples.